# Magento 2.3.1 - Issue with script Google Tag Manager (GTM) in <HEAD>

Tags: head, google, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement GTM in magento 2.3.1. But i could not able to make it successful.

I have used the extension WeltPixel Extension to configure GTM to my site and manually method too but when it inject the code in the `<head>` it's show a bank code, just show the comment but no `<script>`

[image]

**Google tag Assistant:**

[image: Google Tag Assistant]

php Version 7.2

Comment: Are there any config screens you can share?

Comment: Sure! it's the extension config Welt> http://prntscr.com/oeaf8l

Answer (score 0):

Looking a the screenshot you provided you will have to raise with extension developer as there is no misconfiguratuon.  Either this or try another GTM extension.

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-google-tag-manager